# Join SQL Server tables to Excel sheet in Sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I need to create a report where I join tables from a SQL Server database to an Excel spreadsheet in SharePoint.  I wouldn't be able to manually import the Excel sheet as the report would need to be run automatically each morning.

I was hoping to join via a database link or something similar, but I can't find anything on how to do this.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific to get a decent answer. I've done something similar before. There are many ways to get the SQL data into your workbook and then "join" using excel functions and tables.

Comment: At this point I don't have any more specifics.  I was just told about what I'll need to do for an upcoming report.  I've never even seen SharePoint.  I was hoping to get an idea of whether it's even possible before I actually start it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try my best here and see if it help you :) Is your sharepoint implementation on prem. or cloud?

These steps are for on prem. for cloud you need to contact Microsoft 365 support center to make sure that Business intelligence in Excel and Excel Services are on and you have the license for it.

Step 1:
Make sure you have Excel Services enabled

Step2:
Use this article to connect SQL to Excel
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-SQL-Server-database-to-your-workbook-Power-Query-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad

Comment: Thanks,  I'll have to find out what we're using.  I've never even seen SharePoint before.